# rails scaffolding separating frontend from backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, model, scaffolding

First of all, I have only worked with scaffolding in rails.
What I want to do is I want to separate R in CRUD to different route, so that front end will only have R and the rest of CRUD is in backend.

To achieve this I have two options, generating two scaffolds for the same model, or generating a small controller and view for the front end part. Which choice would be better?

May be I can also use multiple layouts with single controller, but I thought it would be messy with controlling the authentication, am I correct?

My site is not going to be much complicated, not in future either.

Since I want to use devise for authentication, I think it wont be complicated using 2 controllers and 2 views for the same mddel.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Regards

Comment: So you want users to be only able to read, and have some sort of an admin which can do CRUD actions?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I want to do, may be it can also be done with multiple layouts on a single controller?

Comment: You can also do that and create a before_filter checking if user is admin on the CRUD actions. But if you're using activerecord, it will save you a lot of time to just use active_admin.

Comment: yes that looks like straight forward method of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you do not want to have all the CRUD actions for your user. I am not sure though what you mean by generate two scaffolds for the same model.

But yes, based on the requirements you gave, you should be fine with generating two controllers/views for the model.

But if you're using ActiveRecord and want backend/admin functionality, you may want to check out [active_admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin). It automatically generates the admin part of your application, which can be very helpful.

Also check out the [active_admin railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin).